# My .find function is not calling my database

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, mongoose-schema

My .find function is not working. It is not calling my database and returning an error of:

```
TypeError: beerSchema.findOne is not a function
```

My other pages display fine, it is just the page, I am trying to load the database on.

```
app.get("/beers", function(req, res){
  //Get all beers
  beerSchema.find({}, function(err, beers){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("beers", {beers: beers});
    }
  });
});
```

`BeerSchema:`

```
var beerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name:String, 
    abv: Number, 
    type:String, 
    Brewery:String, 
    Image:String 
}); 
var beer = mongoose.model("Beer", beerSchema );
```

I get the error that .find is not a function.

Comment: Please share you `beerSchema` code.

Comment: `var beerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  abv: Number, 
  type:String, 
  Brewery:String,
  Image:String 
}); 

var beer = mongoose.model("Beer", beerSchema );`

Answer (score 1):

You need the *model* not the *schema*. Wherever you're making your schema, change this:

```
module.exports = beerSchema;
```

To this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Beer", beerSchema);
```

Then import this in your app file:

```
const { Beer } = require("./beer.js");
```

And use `Beer`:

```
Beer.find({}, function(err, beers) {...});
```

Side note: ES6 shorthand property notation means instead of this:

```
res.render("beers", { beers: beers });
```

You can just do:

```
res.render("beers", { beers });
```